# Python Requests - Can't use a string in my request

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests, nameerror

I am trying to login to a website using python requests. I want to use a string input to give the user the option to use their own email and password. But when I try to use the string I get the following error:

```
  File "c:\Users\NAME\Desktop\newcode\checkout.py", line 93, in <module>
    Checkout()
  File "c:\Users\NAME\Desktop\newcode\checkout.py", line 12, in Checkout
    'inUserName': LOGIN,
NameError: name 'LOGIN' is not defined
```

Here is my  code:

```
from profiles import profiles




def Checkout():

    profiles()

    login = {
        'inUserName': LOGIN, 
        'inUserPass': PASSWORD

    }

    with requests.Session() as s:
        p = s.post('https://EXAMPLEWEBSITE.com/account/login', data=login)
```

Here is the file profiles :

```
def profiles():
    LOGIN = input("Enter your login email: ")
    print(LOGIN)
    PASSWORD = input("Enter your login password: ")
    print(PASSWORD)
```

Answer (score 1):

`LOGIN` and `PASSWORD` are stored in the wrong scope. They are not available within your dictionary. You can return LOGIN and PASSWORD from your profiles method to store them in the right scope.

```py
def profiles():
    LOGIN = input("Enter your login email: ")
    print(LOGIN)
    PASSWORD = input("Enter your login password: ")
    print(PASSWORD)
    return LOGIN, PASSWORD
```

and then use it like this:

```
LOGIN, PASSWORD = profiles()
login = {
    'inUserName': LOGIN, 
    'inUserPass': PASSWORD
}
```

Now LOGIN and PASSWORD are available within your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```py
def Checkout():

    LOGIN, PASSWORD = profiles()
    login = {
        'inUserName': LOGIN, 
        'inUserPass': PASSWORD

    }

    with requests.Session() as s:
        p = s.post('https://EXAMPLEWEBSITE.com/account/login', data=login)
        
def profiles():
    LOGIN = input("Enter your login email: ")
    print(LOGIN)
    PASSWORD = input("Enter your login password: ")
    print(PASSWORD)
    return LOGIN, PASSWORD
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).